# ODP.NET OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters for 9i

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I have Oracle9i Release 2 ODAC installed and we are migrating from Microsoft .NET Data Provider for Oracle.
We have some SqlCommand caching implemented, that uses 
System.Data.SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(result) (var result is type of SqlCommand),
but there is no DeriveParameters() method until ODP.NET version 10.

Perhaps anyone has experience using ODP.NET 10.1.XXXXXX or greater with Oracle 9i and has no problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ODP.NET R2 for 10g on 9i without problems, as stated in the readme documentation of odp.net R2. I'd go for the R2 version (so 2.10.2.xxx) as it has a native .NET 2.0 build and many bugfixes not present in the 10.1 version. It also is less buggy than the 9.2.0.xxx version.

It will install the 10g client, which can access Oracle databases of version 8i R3 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

You can even use odp.net 11.1.0.6.20 together with Oracle 9i. However use Oracle server 9.2.0.7, not 9.2.0.6 .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following document from Metalink, it might help. It contains a support matrix of ODP Driver Version, Supported Operating System, SQL*Net, RDBMS, .NET Framework, and Visual Studio.

Subject: Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP) Supported Configurations

Doc ID: 726240.1